# Spring bean reference not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have the following bean:

```
  package com.test;
  @Component
  public class Sample{

      String modified = null;

      @Value("${url}")
      private String url;

      public Sample(){
       System.out.println(url );
        if(baseUrl.equals(""){
            throw new RuntimeException("missing");
         }
        else{
           modified = "test"+url;
        }
      }
    }
```

I have added:

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties"/> &    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
```

and trying to access above "modified" field as below

```
  <bean id="url" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="#{sample.modified}" />
    </bean>
```

in my application context. But I keep getting the following error:

```
Field or property 'sample' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
```

Not sure why i get this error?

Comment: Where's baseUrl?

Comment: After reading your edit, I wonder if it has to do with timing of XML bean construction and component scan.  Can you move your "Sample" bean into the XML.  I bet it would work there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Spring creates the object it uses the default constructor.  It can't set the property until after it constructs it.  Instead of what you have, try this to see if the value is being set.

```
  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
   System.out.println(url );
    if(baseUrl.equals(""){
        throw new RuntimeException("missing");
     }
  }
```

Comment: i am trying to access  trying to access above "modified" field as below
  <bean id="url" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="#{sample.modified}" />
    </bean>
But I keep getting the following error:
Field or property 'sample' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory

Comment: So you mean ${sample.modified} ?

Answer (score 0):

JustinKSU's answer is right. You have another option: inject value via constructor using `@Autowired`:

```
@Component
public class Sample {

  @Autowired
  public Sample(@Value("${url}") String url) {
    System.out.println(url);
    if(url.equals("") {
      throw new RuntimeException("missing");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is another issue. I am tryin to access propety of Sample in application context but it does not work                       <bean id="ftpUrl" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="#{sample.testUrl}" />
    </bean>                                                                                              I get error  Field or property 'sample' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpress

Comment: Please, edit your question so we can see better what's your problem